# presentViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this piece of code where I present the alert :

```
func arraysize() -> [Int]? {

    let title = "Your file is empty"
    let message = "Please refer to the instructions"
    let okText = "OK"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)

    do{
        ....

        if array?.isEmpty == true{
            print("the array is empty")
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }            

    } 
    catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    return array
}
```

However my alert doesn't show. It used to show and although I haven't changed any code it stopped working for me. Can somebody help me understand what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I am also getting this warning :

> [16632:713433] Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Could this be it?

Comment: Does it print: "the array is empty"?

Comment: @khuong291 yep it does, and then continues skips to other code in my class.

Comment: Yes, because there is no loop here, you use "do-try-catch"

Comment: @khuong291 correct, but its still supposed to show the alert right?

Comment: @khuong291 yeah i know in theory its supposed to but it doesn't unfortunately and i can't figure out why :(

Comment: Read the warning. That's the critical part. Now search on that error. It has been [discussed here many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Attempt+to+present+UIAlertController+whose+view+is+not+in+the+window+hierarchy).

Comment: Basically, your `arraysize` function is in a view controller and that view controller has never been shown on screen. Therefore it can't present any other view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy i have tried a couple of answers I saw in SO before posting my question, and nothing worked for me. If you have any suggestions I could try out I would be very grateful.

Comment: Did you see my last comment? Is that the case here?

Comment: @rmaddy yes that is true. I am calling this function from a VC that is never shown on the screen

Comment: There you go. You can't do that. As the message indicates, you can only display a view controller from a view controller that is itself already in view.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you, got it.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy explained in the comments, my problem was that I was trying to show an alert from the controller that never appears on the actual screen. I fixed this by calling this method from a controller that appears on the screen and it worked.